# How to get correct width of element with ref in react componentDidUpdate

Tags: html, css, reactjs

I am trying to add frozen columns in table (with fixed className). My aim is add left css property to header elements. Left property will calculate from previous header element's width. I am collecting headers ref in render. In componentDidUpdate set the left property to header element. Getting width with getBoundingClientRect and it gives me wrong width (normally: 124px - getting 91px). How can I get correct width ?

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
    let totalWidth = 0
    this._headers.map(header => {
        let header1 = ReactDOM.findDOMNode(header).getBoundingClientRect()
        let thDom = ReactDOM.findDOMNode(header)
        if(thDom.className.includes('fixed')) {
            thDom.style.left = `${totalWidth}px`
        }
        totalWidth += header1.width
    })
}
```

[image: My headers computed values]

[image: Next header calculates left property from previous header's width]

Comment: can you reproduce that in a https://codesandbox.io/

Comment: @Yushan Sorry I cannot. Isn't it clear enough ?

Comment: Issue can cause dependencies than this code like CSS styles

Answer (score 0):

Adding document.body.onload = this.onLoad in componentDidMount and doing all calculations in onLoad function solved mu issue.

```
componentDidMount() {
    document.body.onload = this.onLoad
}

onLoad() {
    let totalWidth = 0
    this._headers.map(header => {
        let header1 = ReactDOM.findDOMNode(header).getBoundingClientRect()
        let thDom = ReactDOM.findDOMNode(header)
        if(thDom.className.includes('fixed')) {
            thDom.style.left = `${totalWidth}px`
        }
        totalWidth += header1.width
    })
}
```

Comment: This is probably not a good idea, since you're overwriting a global handler per-component. Additionally, `ReactDOM.findDOMNode()` is not recommended anymore; you should use refs instead.